# Not understanding ring structure

Tags: rings

I want to learn Elisp so I'm trying to solve perl6 weekly challenges. There is one on [the week 48](https://perlweeklychallenge.org/blog/perl-weekly-challenge-048/):

> Survivor
>
> There are 50 people standing in a circle in position 1 to 50. The
>   person standing at position 1 has a sword. He kills the next person
>   i.e. standing at position 2 and pass on the sword to the immediate
>   next i.e. person standing at position 3. Now the person at position 3
>   does the same and it goes on until only one survives.
>
> Write a script to find out the survivor.

I want to implement it using rings and see how the sequence is descending, but it seems that when it has two elements it is not working properly, or probably I do not get the point:

```el
ELISP> (setf r (ring-convert-sequence-to-ring (number-sequence 1 5)))
(0 5 .
   [5 4 3 2 1])

ELISP> (princ-list (ring-remove r 1) r)
2(0 4 . [5 4 3 1 nil])

"
"
ELISP> (princ-list (ring-remove r 2) r)
4(0 3 . [5 3 1 nil nil])

"
"
ELISP> (princ-list (ring-remove r 3) r)
1(0 2 . [5 3 nil nil nil])

"
"
ELISP> (princ-list (ring-remove r 4) r)
3(0 1 . [5 nil nil nil nil])

"
"
```

Maybe at the end of each loop I need to change it but working in another way I get:

```el
ELISP> (setf r (ring-convert-sequence-to-ring (number-sequence 5 1 -1)))
(0 5 .
   [1 2 3 4 5])

ELISP> (princ-list (setf (car r) 1) (ring-remove r) (ring-resize r 4) r)
120(0 4 . [3 4 5 1])

"
"
ELISP> (princ-list (setf (car r) 1) (ring-remove r) (ring-resize r 3) r)
140(0 3 . [5 1 3])

"
"
ELISP> (princ-list (setf (car r) 1) (ring-remove r) (ring-resize r 2) r)
110(0 2 . [3 5])

"
"
ELISP> (princ-list (setf (car r) 1) (ring-remove r) (ring-resize r 1) r)
150(0 1 . [nil])

"

"
```

But I do not understand the last step.

So firstly I want to know how ring works, and are there circular linked lists in EmacsLisp?

Or maybe I need to focus on the recursive solution of the problem, and not work with circular linked lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to implement it using rings and see how the sequence is descending, but it seems that when it has two elements it is not working properly, or probably I do not get the point

It seems to be working as expected in your example. The key thing to note about rings is that they are modulo-indexed, i.e. if you have the ring `(3 5)` (from newest element to oldest) and try to remove the element at index `4`, then you will be left with the ring `(5)`, as the index `4` modulo the length of the ring `2` is `0`, which corresponds to the newest element, which in this case is `3`.

> But I do not understand the last step.

The last step should make more sense if you read the docstring of `ring-resize`:

```
ring-resize is a compiled Lisp function in `ring.el'.

(ring-resize RING SIZE)

Set the size of RING to SIZE.
If the new size is smaller, then the oldest items in the ring are
discarded.
```

Before calling `ring-resize`, you have the ring `(1 1 . [nil 3])` with size `2`, length `1`, and oldest element `3` at index `1`.

Resizing to `1` means getting rid of the oldest element `3`, leaving you with the ring `(nil)`.

The reason this is not a bug in the `ring.el` package is because you are manually changing the "head" (i.e. the index of the oldest element). The ring structure wouldn't have reached the state `(1 1 . [nil 3])` if you used its public API. As [Tobias notes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/55629/15748), the ring structure itself is an internal implementation detail and not to be relied on externally.

> are there circular linked lists in EmacsLisp

Yes, see [`(elisp) Cons Cells`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Cons-Cells.html). For example:

```el
(let ((l (list 1 2)))
  (nth 2 l)   ; => nil
  (nconc l l) ; Loop back to the start
  (nth 2 l))  ; => 1
```

> Or maybe I need to focus on the recursive solution of the problem, and not work with circular linked lists.

Actually, I think circular lists are probably the simplest and most efficient solution to this problem in Elisp.

Here's a sample circular solution:

```el
(defun my-survivor-circular (first last)
  "Solve the Survivor puzzle for numbers FIRST through LAST.
Return the single surviving number.
Implemented using a circular list."
  (let ((circle (number-sequence first last)))
    ;; Make circle circular
    (nconc circle circle)
    ;; Kill next person so long as they are not us
    (while (not (eq circle (cdr circle)))
      (setcdr circle (cddr circle))
      ;; Pass sword to next survivor
      (pop circle))
    ;; Return single survivor
    (or (car circle) first)))

(my-survivor-circular 1  0) ; =>  1
(my-survivor-circular 1  1) ; =>  1
(my-survivor-circular 1  2) ; =>  1
(my-survivor-circular 1  3) ; =>  3
(my-survivor-circular 1  4) ; =>  1
(my-survivor-circular 1  5) ; =>  3
(my-survivor-circular 1 50) ; => 37
```

Here's the same idea but without using circular lists:

```el
(defun my-survivor-proper (first last)
  "Solve the Survivor puzzle for numbers FIRST through LAST.
Return the single surviving number.
Implemented using a proper list."
  (let* ((circle (number-sequence first last))
         (sword  circle))
    ;; As long as there is more than one survivor
    (while (cdr circle)
      ;; Kill next person or one at beginning
      (if (cdr sword)
          (setcdr sword (cddr sword))
        (pop circle))
      ;; Pass sword to next survivor or wrap around to beginning
      (setq sword (or (cdr sword) circle)))
    ;; Return single survivor
    (or (car circle) first)))

(my-survivor-proper 1  0) ; =>  1
(my-survivor-proper 1  1) ; =>  1
(my-survivor-proper 1  2) ; =>  1
(my-survivor-proper 1  3) ; =>  3
(my-survivor-proper 1  4) ; =>  1
(my-survivor-proper 1  5) ; =>  3
(my-survivor-proper 1 50) ; => 37
```

And finally here's a sample solution using rings:

```el
(defun my-survivor-ring (first last)
  "Solve the Survivor puzzle for numbers FIRST through LAST.
Return the single surviving number.
Implemented using a ring."
  (let ((ring  (ring-convert-sequence-to-ring (number-sequence first last)))
        (sword first))
    (while (> (ring-length ring) 1)
      (let* ((kill (ring-next ring sword))
             (next (ring-next ring kill)))
        (ring-remove ring (ring-member ring kill))
        (setq sword next)))
    (if (ring-empty-p ring) first sword)))

(my-survivor-ring 1  0) ; =>  1
(my-survivor-ring 1  1) ; =>  1
(my-survivor-ring 1  2) ; =>  1
(my-survivor-ring 1  3) ; =>  3
(my-survivor-ring 1  4) ; =>  1
(my-survivor-ring 1  5) ; =>  3
(my-survivor-ring 1 50) ; => 37
```

As you can see, the ring does not lend itself as neatly or as efficiently to this problem as a circular list. I think this is because a ring's circularity is inherent in its index, rather than its data, and perhaps because Emacs' ring API could be enriched.

Comment: really great explained, working with circular lists in Elisp

Answer (score 3):

Don't look at the innards of the ring. That is an implementation detail.
Look at the results of the [interface functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rings.html).

You can see what's in the ring with `ring-elements`. The list indexes of that list are also the indexes of the elements in the ring.

```el
(let ((r (ring-convert-sequence-to-ring (number-sequence 1 5))))
  (ring-elements r))
```

(1 2 3 4 5)

Let us remove element 1 and look at the resulting list:

```el
(let ((r (ring-convert-sequence-to-ring (number-sequence 1 5))))
  (ring-remove r 1)
  (ring-elements r))
```

(1 3 4 5)

The element 2 is removed.

If we reference the new element at index 1 we get 3:

```el
(let ((r (ring-convert-sequence-to-ring (number-sequence 1 5))))
  (ring-remove r 1)
  (ring-ref r 1))
```

3

So the solution of the task at hand is:

```el
;; (org-src-debug)
(let ((r (ring-convert-sequence-to-ring (number-sequence 1 50)))
      l)
  (setf i 0)
  (while (> (setq l (ring-length r)) 1)
    (ring-remove r (setq i (mod (1+ i) l))))
  (ring-ref r 0))
```

37

`i` kills its current successor with index `(mod (1+ i) l))` where `l` is the current length of the ring. The successor of the killed takes the place of the killed (we let do that the ring).

Comment: There is a bug in your ring solution when incrementing the index past the length of the ring; the correct answer should be 37. The bug should become clearer if you test it on a circle with numbers 1 through 5, where the correct answer should be 3 instead of 5.

Comment: Yes, if i becomes equal to the length of the ring i is incremented but the length is decremented simultaneously. I end up at the second element instead of the first. That's the problem.

Comment: @Basil Corrected.

Comment: Thanks for your effort in this question, I really learned a lot from your answers